# Sorting group collection after query with aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, aggregate, nest

I use aggregate to get all users have same name, but whenever I query to this API, the results return are not sorted even thought I add $sort by 'name' field.

```
const aggregateQuery: any = [
            { $group: { _id: '$name', count: { $sum: 1 }, users: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
            { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } },
            { $unwind: '$users' },
            { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$users' } },
            { $sort: { name: 1 } }
        ];`

        const users = await this.userRepository.getModel().aggregate(aggregateQuery).exec();
```

The order of the records is not sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to sort `case insensitively`
Let's say you need `name` and `age`,

Try this query :

`[ { "$project": { "name": 1, "age" : 1, "insensitive": { "$toLower": "$name" } }},{ $group: { _id: '$name', count: { $sum: 1 }, users: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } }, { $match: { count: { $gte: 1 } } }, { $unwind: '$users' }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$users' } }, { $sort: { insensitive: 1 } } ]`

If you have more fields to be added to the output, then instead of the above query, try the below one.

`[ { "$project": { "name": 1,   createdAt : 1 }},{ $group: { _id: '$name', count: { $sum: 1 }, users: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } }, { $match: { count: { $gte: 1 } } }, {"$addFields":{"users.insensitive": { "$toLower": "$_id" },}}, { $unwind: '$users' }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$users' } }, { $sort: { insensitive: 1 } } ]`

Comment: The sorting is work in this case but It seems that data only returns 1 name field, I want to return other fields too

Comment: So, did we have option to return all field ?

Comment: Yes, you just have to mention the `field` name in the `project` json with value to `1`

Comment: So, If we have 50 fields, we must be put all field to option. Do you have any ideal to with another way ?

Comment: And @sachin, the results also return the field not have same same. I meant query above return all users. I just want to return the users have the same name and sort them

Comment: According to the first question ( regarding 50 fields ), there's an updated query in the answer, please look at it. And I did not get your second question clearly.

Comment: May be I have a problem when compare ipAddress. the Ip have the format 127.0.0.1 and they just compared 127.0 ( 2 component of IP) . I tried to use substr but it's not work

Comment: I want to return all users have absolute same ip